# Vertical dropdown menu not showing properly

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

I have horizontal & vertical menu in header section and vertical menu need to show the submenu as dropdown on click event, Horizontal menu also has submenus which are not shown in this example as i am stuck with the vertical menu `More Menu` as [image]

Codepen: https://codepen.io/KGuide/pen/jOEpzQo
in below code `Media` submenu items should show under Media rather it shows them at the bottom, how can i fix this as per image shown

```
    <div class="menu-w">
  <a href="">Menu One</a>
   <a href="">Menu Two</a>
  <a href="">Menu Three</a>
  <a href="">Menu Four</a>
</div>

<div class="menu-w">
  <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">More Menu</a>
  <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
    <li>
      <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Media</a>
      <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">News</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Video Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Blog</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Directory</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a> </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just remove .list-unstyled from the #pageSubmenu ul